# Disable close-window in iterm2

Tags: macos, iterm2

`ctrl` + `D` closes an `iterm2` window. Where's this option to disable it? I can't find it in `preferences`->`keys` or `preferences`->`general`.

Comment: Control-D is EOF (End of file). Searching for shell closure on end of term might help. (Not sure since I have no OS/X to test it with).

Comment: @Hennes I didn't know that. I've set a `zsh` option (`ignoreeof`) so the shell won't close for me when I accidentally hit it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Let me move it to an answer so we can close this question. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Control-D is EOF (End of file).  Sending end of file to a shell session usually closes the shell.

You can set IGNOREEOF to force the user to type `exit` or `logout` instead of just pressing ^D.